# Metric a Ricci curvature of Riemannian product manifold between two curves

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $M(u,v)=N_1(u) \times N_2(v)$ be a 2-dimensional Riemannian product manifold, so $N_1(u)$ and $N_2(v)$ are 1-dimensional curve.

Is correct that, since $N_1$ is naturally embeded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and the same for $N_2$), then $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^4$, so $M$ has metric: $g_M=g_{N_1} + g_{N_2}$, with $g_{N_1}=g_{11}du^2$ and $g_{N_2}=g_{44}dv^2$ respectively?

Is corrected to say that write $g_{N_2}=g_{22}dv^2$ is wrong?

Because $M$ is Ricci flat and if the metric of $M$ is $g_M=g_{N_1} + g_{N_2}$, with $g_{N_1}=g_{11}du^2$ and $g_{N_2}=g_{22}dv^2$, then $M$ could be not Ricci flat.

Comment: That all depends on the local coordinates you are working with. If those are the standard global coordinates on $\mathbb R^4$, both expressions will apply only when you curves are straight lines.

Comment: @wisefool - Thank you. Certainly because the parameterizations must lead to the Ricci tensor disappearing, if this is not possible the manifold cannot be parameterized in that way. Do you mean this?

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by "$N_{1}$ is naturally embedded in the plane", and by "$M$ could not be Ricci flat"? <> Under the stated conditions, $M$ is globally isometric to either a flat product torus, a flat cylinder, or a Euclidean plane. Particularly, you may as well assume $g_{M} = du^2 + dv^2$.

Comment: The two expressions $g_{22}dv^2$ and $g_{44}dv^2$ are meaningless unless you specify how the global coordinates on $\mathbb R^4$ (wrt which you are writing your metric tensor $g$, I suppose) relate to the local coordinate $v$ on $N$.
In other words: what are $g_{22}$ and $g_{44}$ ?

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, but I think I have solved my doubt. In practice a product between curves must always be flat Ricci, so if I consider the metric as the metric of a surface it must be a flat metric, otherwise not can represent a product of curves. Am I right?